# Animating the background image of a button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I was very impressed of how The wikipedia app looks in wp7 and facinated on how the moving background of the buttons work.

I wanted to do a similar thing, any ideas on how i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple way to do it:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
    <Image.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="Shift">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Translation"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateY"
                                AutoReverse="True"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:5"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Translation"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX"
                                AutoReverse="True"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Image.Resources>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="Translation"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

With MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Shift.Begin();
}
```

Comment: it worked well a picture, is there anyway to place the moving picture inside the button. I did try but it j